# Sorting Documents in Site Content and Structure - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-and-structure

I need to move large amounts of documents between document libraries and I am using the Move function on Site Content and Structure. When I did this earlier it was easy enough, but now I am for some reason unable to sort by Column data. There used to be options beneath "Sort Descending" but they are gone now.

[image: screenshot]

Any advice on how to get the other options back?